# Network drive connected via ForkLift not accessible via Finder nor Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, mount, webdav

When I connect to a WebDAV network drive via ForkLift (using CMD+K shorcut), I only see that drive in ForkLift, I cannot access it via Finder nor Terminal. Why is that and how can I access it with Finder and Terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Because you connected to it with Forklift.  The OS does not support masquerading WebDAV shares as mounts.  If you want it to behave like a mount, use something like ExpanDrive.

Comment: @MarcWilson Thanks for the reply, but why?

Comment: Why... what?  Why doesn't the OS support mounting a WebDAV export?  You'd have to ask Apple.  Meanwhile, there are several products out there that shim it into the OS, most of the time by using FUSE.

Comment: @MarcWilson could give some examples of such products?

Comment: I already did,  Another would be Mountain Duck.